# WHM warning about invalid permissions on /etc/shadow, "Expected: 3377602730, Actual: 0644"

Tags: permissions, centos, cpanel, whm

I've been getting some alert messages sent by my WHM instance, warning about invalid permissions on my shadow file. However, the actual permissions (`0400`) seem correct, and the permissions it reports seem to be very large... numbers?

From this morning:

```
/etc/shadow has non default permissions. Expected: 2401450770, Actual: 0400.
Review the permissions on /etc/shadow to ensure they are safe
```

From this evening:

```
/etc/shadow has non default permissions. Expected: 3377602730, Actual: 0400.
Review the permissions on /etc/shadow to ensure they are safe
```

What do these reported permissions mean, and why is WHM not happy with `0400`?

Comment: Which message are you getting: the one in your title or the one(s) in the body of your question?  ... … … …  I don't know what's going on, but here are some observations that might help others: both numbers are multiples of 8 (as is obvious from the fact that their last digits are 0) but not multiples of 16 (note that the penultimate digits are odd).  Also, they are both > 2²⁸ and < 2²⁹.

Comment: Well, no matter how you look at it, WHM (WebHost Manager?) seems to be malfunctioning *ever so slightly*. Are you yourself responsible for the management software (not “instance”) deployment?

Comment: @DanielB Not _really_, this is a Cloud VPS through a hosting provider. (A Small Orange.) I can definitely shoot them an email, but this is a personal/low-priority server so I was just hoping to learn a bit and see if I couldn't diagnose or resolve the issue on my own. I do have root access to the WHM web interface, but I don't know if that necessarily grants me the ability to upgrade the WHM software itself.

Comment: Well you should definitely contact support. The issue you’re experiencing seems benign, but who knows what else is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at source. Try set permissions 0200 or 0600.

```
sub _check_for_unsafe_permissions {
my ($self) = @_;

my %test_files = (
    '/etc/shadow' => { 'perms' => [ 0200, 0600 ], 'uid' => 0, 'gid' => 0 },
    '/etc/passwd' => { 'perms' => [0644], 'uid' => 0, 'gid' => 0 }
);

for my $file ( keys %test_files ) {
    my $expected_attributes = $test_files{$file};
    my ( $current_mode, $uid, $gid ) = ( stat($file) )[ 2, 4, 5 ];
    my $perms_ok = 0;
    foreach my $allowed_perms ( @{ $expected_attributes->{'perms'} } ) {
        if ( ( $allowed_perms & 07777 ) == ( $current_mode & 07777 ) ) {
            $perms_ok = 1;
            last;
        }
    }
    if ( !$perms_ok ) {
        my $expected_mode = sprintf( "%04o", $expected_attributes->{'perms'} );
        my $actual_mode   = sprintf( "%04o", $current_mode & 07777 );
        $self->add_warn_advice(
            'text'       => ["$file has non default permissions.  Expected: $expected_mode, Actual: $actual_mode."],
            'suggestion' => ["Review the permissions on $file to ensure they are safe"]
        );
    }

    if ( $uid != $expected_attributes->{'uid'} or $gid != $expected_attributes->{'gid'} ) {
        $self->add_warn_advice(
            'text'       => ["$file has non root user and/or group"],
            'suggestion' => ["Review the ownership permissions
```

The expected permission output should be a 4 character octal formated value but looks like perl's sprint function is improperly displaying the multidimensional array value which is displaying garbage.

> Source (The Security Advisor is found within the Security Center of WHM - Cpanel)
>   https://github.com/bdraco/addon_securityadvisor
>   https://github.com/bdraco/addon_securityadvisor/blob/master/pkg/Cpanel/Security/Advisor/Assessors/Permissions.pm